Is there anyway to guarantee probability mass coverage?
If I have a probability density function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I can sample $m$ points from it. Is there anyway to get an estimate of how much probability mass is covered by balls of radius $\delta$ around each of the $m$ points?
My intuition is that if the balls intersect then I should be able to say that the distribution is somewhat concentrated and w.h.p I have covered some mass? But are there any formal results stating something like this?
What can be some very mild assumptions that can allow me to do something like this?

I would like some PAC guarantee on how much mass I covered, I think with kernel density, I can gaurentee that for the kernel density itself, but not for the true distribution. But if I can loosely transfer those gaurentees to the true distribution, in some formal way then I will be happy
